# How would you add root element to json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am creating json dynamically

```
    let schema = fs.readFileSync(`my_schema.json`, {encoding: 'utf8'});
    //need to add root to json schema before save
    result.def =  JSON.parse(schema); 

   fs.writeFile(`my_json.json`, JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

then when I writing it to the file I've got:

```
"result.def" = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "type": "object",
   ...
}
```

but I need:

```
"result.def" = {
 "item": {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result.def = { item: JSON.parse(schema) };
```

or

```
result.def.item = JSON.parse(schema);
```

or

```
result = { def: { item: JSON.parse(schema) } };
```

depending on what levels already exist and when you want to populate them.

Comment: That implies that `schema` is invalid JSON.

Comment: just because had some `experiments` going, now all good. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
result.def = { "item": JSON.parse(schema) }
```